# How can you store the typed info in strings?

Tags: java, jtextfield

I need the thing I type in the text field to store in a string so I can use that string in another class.

```
public void jButton1_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String sql = "Select * from clients where username=? and password=?";
    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, jTextField.getText());

        pst.setString(2, new String(jPasswordField.getPassword())); // /
```

I need this username I type in the jTextField to store as a string.

Comment: what's wrong with `String string = jTextField.getText();` ?

Comment: It's already stored as String and you can get it by calling getText() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the text to put it in your PreparedStatement like this:

```
pst.setString(1, jTextField.getText());
```

You can use the same method to save it in a String:

```
String username = jTextField.getText();
```